# How to read from the TSYS03 temperature sensor?

Tags: stm32

I am using the STM32 Nucleo L432CK and want to read from the thermo 20 clickboard (MIKROE-4316) which uses the TSYS03 temperature sensor, but I do not get anything. Would appreciate if someone could help me. [TSYS03 Datasheet](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Data%20Sheet%7FTSYS03%7FA%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_DS_TSYS03_A.pdf%7FCAT-DTS0001?te_bu=Sen&te_type=pr&te_campaign=oth_glo_sen-oth-global-pr-oth-ds-tsys03_sma-1362_12&elqCampaignId=87467)

My code:

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
static const uint8_t TSYS03_ADDR = 0x40 << 1; // Standard I2C-Address (Device-Address) 
static const uint8_t REG_TEMP = 0x00; // Read ADC
/* USER CODE END PV */

int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
  HAL_StatusTypeDef ret;
  uint8_t buf[12];
  uint16_t val;
  float temp_c; // Temperatur als Dezimalzahl (in Celsius)
  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  while (1)
  {
      // Teile dem Sensor mit, dass wir von seinem Temperatur-Register lesen wollen
      buf[0] = REG_TEMP;
      ret = HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, TSYS03_ADDR, buf, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
      if (ret != HAL_OK) {
          strcpy((char*)buf, "ERROR TX\r\n");
      } else {
          // Read two Bytes from temperature register
          ret = HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, TSYS03_ADDR, buf, 2, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
          if (ret != HAL_OK) {
              strcpy((char*)buf, "ERROR RX\r\n");
          } else {
              // Combine the Bytes
              val = ((int16_t)buf[0] << 4) | (buf[1] >> 4);

              // Konvertiere zu 2er-Kompliment, da die Temperatur auch negativ sein kann
              if (val > 0x7FF) {
                  val |= 0xF00;
              }
              }
          }
      }

      // Gibt den Buffer aus (Temperatur oder Error-Meldungen)
      HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, buf, strlen((char*)buf), HAL_MAX_DELAY);

      // Warten
      HAL_Delay(500);

    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
```

Comment: Draw a schematics on how you connected, did you use mxcube to define I2C? Did mxcube generate the initial code?

Comment: I am using the STM32CubeIDE.
Settings of I2C and UART are correctly. At the beginning I tested the UART with a simple code example, to print out some text on Putty. This worked perfectly.
The I2C is also connected correct with the temperature sensor.
The supply voltage of the sensor is 3.3V.
Initial code was also generated.

Comment: There are too little details about the problem. What have you discovered so far. How are you so confident that settings are correct? What help do you expect, since there is no description?

Comment: My big problem is, that I do not understand the datasheet very well. I am not sure how to find out, which the temperature register is.
Furthermore I am not sure if I should instead of my current code use HAL_I2C_MEM_READ and HAL_I2C_MEM_WRITE to access the registers. I have never used these functions.

Comment: Have you debugged the code in any way? Single stepped through each line to see what it does? Is that all code? No I2C initialization, no GPIO initialization, no initialization of anything?